# How to use wm_concat one a column that already exists in the query?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, string-aggregation

So... I am currently using Oracle 11.1g and I need to create a query that uses the ID and CusCODE from Table_with_value and checks Table_with_status using the ID to find active CO_status but on different CusCODE.

This is what I have so far - obviously does not work as it should unless CusCODE and ID are provided manually:

```
SELECT wm_concat(CoID) as active_CO_Status_for_same_ID_but_different_CusCODE
FROM Table_with_status
WHERE 
CoID IN (SELECT CoID FROM Table_with_status WHERE ID = Table_with_value.ID AND CusCODE != Table_with_value.CusCODE)) AND Co_status = 'active';
```

**Table_with_value:**

```
|CoID | CusCODE | ID | Value |
|--------|---------|----------|----|
|354223 | 1.432 | 0784296L | 99 |
|321232 | 4.212321.22 | 0432296L | 32 |
|938421 | 3.213 | 0021321L | 93 |
```

**Table_with_status:**

```
|CoID | CusCODE | ID | Co_status|
|--------|--------------|----------|--------|
|354223 | 1.432 | 0784296L | active|
|354232 | 1.432 | 0784296L | inactive |
|666698 | 1.47621 | 0784296L | active |
|666700 | 1.5217 | 0784296L | active |
|938421 | 3.213 | 0021321L | active |
|938422 | 3.213 | 0021321L | active |
|938423 | 3.213 | 0021321L | active |
|321232 | 4.212321.22 | 0432296L | active |
|321232 | 4.212321.22 | 0432296L | active |
|321232 | 1.689 | 0432296L | inactive |
```

**Expected output:**

```
|CoID | active_CO_Status_for_same_ID_but_different_CusCODE  | ID | Value |
|--------|---------|----------|----|
|354223 | 666698,666700 | 1.432 | 0784296L | 99 |
|321232 | N/A | 4.212321.22 | 0432296L | 32 |
|938421 | N/A | 3.213 | 0021321L | 93 |
```

Any idea on how this can be implemented ideally without any PL/SQL for loops, but it should be fine as well since the output dataset is expected < 300 IDs.

I apologize in advance for the cryptic nature in which I structured the question :) Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: "obviously does not work" - why is it obvious; what result do you get now? Do you perhaps just need to `group by ID, CusCode`? And `CoId, Value` for the expected output, perhaps (and include the relevant columns in the select list)?

Comment: Adding the wm_concat(Table_with_status.CoID) and Table_with_value.CoID in the select list is what I really need help with - the way I structured the query, it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description and expected output, it looks like you need a left outer join, something like:

```
SELECT v.CoID,
  wm_concat(s.CoID) as other_active_CusCODE -- active_CO_Status_for_same_ID_but_different_CusCODE
  v.CusCODE,
  v.ID,
  v.value
FROM Table_with_value v
LEFT JOIN Table_with_status s
ON s.ID = v.ID
AND s.CusCODE != v.CusCODE
AND s.Co_status = 'active'
GROUP BY v.CoID, v.CusCODE, v.ID, v.value;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30b46/2) using `listagg()` instead of the never-supported and now-removed `wm_concat()`; with a couple of different approaches if the logic isn't quite what I interpreted. With your sample data they all get:

```
COID   OTHER_ACTIVE_CUSCODE CUSCODE     ID       VALUE
------ -------------------- ----------- -------- -----
321232 (null)               4.212321.22 0432296L    32
354223 666698,666700        1.432       0784296L    99
938421 (null)               3.213       0021321L    93
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot Alex. Unfortunately, listagg() is not available in Oracle 11.1g so wm_concat() will have to do.

Comment: Yes, I noticed you said you were on 11.1 - I had to use listagg() for the fiddle, but left wm_concat() in the answer *8-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it should work, assuming you are referring to the correct tables:

```
SELECT wm_concat(s.CoID) as active_CO_Status_for_same_ID_but_different_CusCODE
FROM Table_with_status s
WHERE s.CoID IN (SELECT v.CoID
                 FROM Table_with_value v
                 WHERE v.ID = s.ID AND
                       v.CusCODE <> s.CusCODE
                ) AND
      s.Co_status = 'active';
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Perhaps I did not phrase it well but how do I add v.Co_ID and wm_concat(s.CoID) to both show as separate columns?

Comment: @MatthewZammit . . . In that case, Alex's answer should do what you want.